# Watchman can monitor only 2 level from roots

Tags: watchman

I using Watchman 4.4.0 version and found problem that watchman can monitor only 2 level directory from roots.

So i not sure what going wrong with this ?

**Directory Structure**

`src/<- set watch roots 
└── Oncmd
    └── Command <- **File under this can't  monitor
        ├── GencmdCommand.php
        ├── InitCommand.php
        └── cmdCommand.php`

**watchman -- watch-list**

```
{
"version": "4.4.0",
"roots": [
    "/home/udomsak/mycmd/src"
]
```

}

**watchman -- trigger-list**

```
{
"version": "4.4.0",
"triggers": [
    {
        "name": "build_phar",
        "append_files": true,
        "command": [
            "./build.sh"
        ],
        "stdin": [
            "name",
            "exists",
            "new",
            "size",
            "mode"
        ],
        "expression": [
            "anyof",
            [
                "match",
                "*",
                "wholename"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 2):

If you run `watchman find /home/udomsak/mycmd/src` and don't see those files in the output, then that is a watchman bug.

However, I think I can see what is causing this to not work how you expect.

The `match` expression you're using won't match the `/` characters that are present in the `wholename` in the way that you expect.

You didn't include details on how you established that trigger, so this advice on how to get the behavior it sounds like you're looking for has a couple of different options.

Option 1, since it looks like you want to trigger for any file changing, is simply to remove the expression term completely.

Option 2, use a recursive glob via the expanded [wildmatch](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/expr/match.html#wildmatch) syntax: `["match", "**/*", "wholename"]`.

Option 3, use [watchman-make](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/watchman-make.html).  Rather than use the `trigger` command, it is often significantly easier to use `watchman-make` for this kind of use case:

```
$ watchman-make --make build_phar -t build -p '**/*'
# Relative to /home/udomsak/mycmd/src
# Changes to files matching **/* will execute `build_phar build`
# waiting for changes
```